# Wrapper for migrating from OpenLayers 2 to 3 or 4?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

How can I migrate my application from OpenLayers 2 to OpenLayers 3 or 4 without any code changes? Is there any wrapper which support OpenLayers 2 code structure but actually call the OpenLayers 3 or 4 methods?

For example, when I run this:

```
map.setCenter(center, 5);
```

It will run the below code in background (something that I call wrapper):

```
old3.getView().setCenter(center); 
old3.getView().setZoom(5);
```

The wrapper is actually a namespace like this:

```
var map = {
 setCenter: function(center,ZoomLevel){
   old3.getView().setCenter(center); 
   old3.getView().setZoom(ZoomLevel); 
 }
};
```

The `map` is wrapper (what I'm looking for) and `ol3` is OpenLayers 3 library

Comment: As of i Know there is no wrapper or tool which will convert openlayers 2 to 3.

Comment: @SumanthShastry Thanks! So I have to write my own wrapper or completely migrate to new OpenLayers.

Comment: Do you mind sharing why you don't want to port it or just stay with ol2?

Comment: @CoreyAlix Actually it's take too many times to write from scratch with ol3 and ol3 is much more flexible to work with. ex: the Raster-Reprojection functionality that implemented in ol3 is one of the feature that I considered to use it.